# Center text with the icon in textButton

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-design

Well the question is probably dumb AF, but I can't figure it out. How can i center this button? Tried gravity and paddings, not with a success

[image]

Button style:

```
 <style name="Theme.Base.Jabotmobile.TextBT"
            parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
            <item name="icon">@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24</item>
            <item name="iconPadding">4dp</item>
            <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
            <item name="fontFamily">@font/open_sans_regular</item>
            <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
            <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
            <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
            <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
            <item name="iconGravity">start</item>
        </style>
```

Button in layout:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/cat_req_BT1"
            style="@style/Theme.JaBotMobile.TextBT"
            android:layout_width="155dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/category_req"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout4" />
```

Comment: @Onik well I thought it doesn't matter here but it's added now

Comment: Inb4 the style import isn't wrong, i use a base tag and then extend for different APIs

Comment: Do you want to center the button in the parent layout?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this constraint to, it should be centered with this way

```
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

**PS**

I understand the problem now, Basically you want to center the button items (icon and text) vertically. Unfortunately I don't have solution for this case, instead of using style you can create a custom view component, with custom view component you can have more flexibility for customizations.

Comment: Can you pls add the whole xml file?

Comment: It's kinda long, but here you are 
https://pastebin.com/miW7fWYP

Buttons at the bottom

Comment: Your design looks like this basically, I couldn't get How you want to align button center, exactly https://ibb.co/gvMRsvk , to support your aim is it possible to provide something like image maybe?

Comment: https://ibb.co/KjBvcK7 Well it looks like this and i wanted the button to go up slightly or the text to lower. It's not like super important, but i like when things are placed  aesthetically.

Comment: adding a random drawable and default textButton style should reproduce the thing

Comment: I understand the problem now, but Unfortunately have no solution for this case, but I suggest you to create a custom view, so you can have full flexibility to make everything like you want.

Comment: Can you add full layout xml in question @Redc4ke